# Java - failing to collect a String when prompted

Tags: java, loops, input, java.util.scanner

When I run the following code inside a do-while loop (omitted); it prints both lines asking for the name of a song & the size at the same time. However, it never collects a String input for the name before asking for the file size.

I need it to collect a String for the name before asking for the file size (which is not occurring).

How is this happening?

```
            //Interface.java
            import java.util.*;
            ...
            Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in); //After importing Scanner.
            ...

            option = console.nextInt(); // User chooses an option (add / delete song, etc.) by pressing a number. Only adding is relevant here.

            do { // Code inside a do-while loop which repeats for entering name / file size on 4 songs.
            song = console.nextInt(); // User chooses to add name / file size to either song1, song2, song3 or song 4 (there is a maximum of 4 song objects).

            System.out.println("Please enter the name of a song.");
            name = console.nextLine();

            System.out.println("Please enter file size in MB.");
            do { // This do-while checks input to be an integer / not negative & then it assigns the input as...
            fileSize = console.nextInt();
            // end of do-while loop which checks the integer.

            // end of do-while loop which lets user add name / size to a maximum of 4 songs.
```

Comment: Please try to provide a "minimum, but executable" code snippet. It is hard to say what is going on; without knowing how you setup your scanner ...

Comment: Your code seems to be working fine: http://ideone.com/RJhwiZ

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/skipping-nextline-after-use-next-nextint-or-other-nextfoo-methods

Comment: @maraca There is no `nextLine` in OP example placed after `nextFoo`.

Comment: @Pshemo right, but there are other cases descriped, we don't know what he does *before* reading the name of the song. Are there any interactinos with the console before asking the name?

Comment: @maraca "*we don't know what he does before reading the name of the song*" yes, and that is why before guessing answers it is better to ask OP for [example with will let us reproduce problem](http://sscce.org/) like Jägermeister did.

Comment: @Pshermo I disagree, because I didn't post it as answer, I wasn't guessing it. It just could be the fast track to the solution if he finds the solution there. Why have him clean up and post everything then people go through his code, just to discover it could have been solved with this link?

Comment: It's confusing to call a `Scanner` `console` when there is also a [`Console`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Console.html).

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Skipping nextLine() after use next(), nextInt() or other nextFoo() methods](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/skipping-nextline-after-use-next-nextint-or-other-nextfoo-methods)

Comment: I think I know the answer: print out content of name, is it: "Please enter the name of a song."? I guess you know where I'm going with this...

Comment: No, it's even funnier, my first link really solves the problem! `nextInt()` doesn't consume the newline character after `option = ...` execute an empty `console.nextLine();` and it should work. I thnk in the do while is also a problem if you enter wrong stufff first.

Comment: @maraca; It prints nothing. Also, it doesn't ever collect information for name as a String even though it asks for it. It basically prints both lines (enter name / file size) & immediately waits for an integer to be checked.

Comment: It was solved once I put console.nextLine(); right after asking for a name. What exactly was happening? I've been programming for a few days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always execute `console.nextLine();` after `console.nextInt();` to consume tne newline character and it should work fine. See here: [Scanner is skipping nextLine() after using next(), nextInt() or other nextFoo() methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/skipping-nextline-after-use-next-nextint-or-other-nextfoo-methods) The reason is that `nextInt()` doesn't consume the newline character (`'\n'`), so there is an empty line there waiting to be consumed.